# Reuse MySQL Connection in other forms VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection, global

I'm pretty new to Visual Basic and right now I have connected my program to the database to save and get input, and that works fine. What I want to do right now is to reuse my connection to the database on other forms. I was thinking to take the global declaration and put them in to a class and making them accessible from there, but I have no idea how to do that. I've tried different methods but I always ending up with some error... I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help that I could get.

Here is some part of the code:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

    'GLOBAL DELARATION
    Dim conString As String = "Server=localhost;" & "Database=data;" & "Uid=password;" & "Pwd=password;"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conString)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'CONSTRUCT DATAGRID VIEW
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "ID"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Name"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Position"
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "TEAM"

        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        Retrieve()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cleartxt()
        TextBox_name.Text = ""
        TextBox_position.Text = ""
        TextBox_team.Text = ""

    End Sub

    'INSERT INTO DB
    Private Sub Add()
        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO people(Name,Position,Team) VALUES(@NAME,@POSITION,@TEAM)"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

        'PARAMETERS
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox_name.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSITION", TextBox_position.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEAM", TextBox_team.Text)

        'Open Connection and INSERT
        Try
            con.Open()
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Produktet er lagt inn korrekt")
                cleartxt()
            End If
            con.Close()
            Retrieve()
        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use a global connection string but create, use, close and dispose of the connection as needed.  The same is true of the other DB Objects *unless* you are configuring a DataAdapter to do everything for you.

Comment: If have to concur with @Plutonix. ADO.NET has been specifically designed to be used that way so don't try to fight it. In actual fact, thanks to connection pooling, if you create multiple `MySqlConnection` objects that all use the same connection string then they will actually use the same database connection at a low level.